# Matlab - Merge two vectors and a matrix with different dimensions

Tags: matlab, matrix, merge

I have two vectors and matrix, for example:

```
a = [ 1 2 3 4];
b = [6 7 8];
c = [ 600 700 800 900; 
      100 200 300 400; 
      777 888 555 333];
```

I would like to get a matrix as:

```
1 6 600
2 6 700
3 6 800
4 6 900
1 7 100
2 7 200
3 7 300
4 7 400
1 8 777
2 8 888
3 8 555
4 8 333
```

Is it possible to get this matrix without using loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, with `meshgrid` for instance:

```
[B, A] = meshgrid(b, a);
C = c';
Res = [A(:) B(:) C(:)];
```

Best,